# Recharts LineChart dots only for certain data points

Tags: javascript, recharts

I would like to use the LineChart of Recharts to show a data set with up to 200 points. However, I would like to show the dots/tooltip/activeDot only for 5 of those data points on small screens because 200 points wouldn't be clickable anymore on smartphones.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: hey, did you end up solving this issue?

Answer (score 9):

In order to only show certain dots you can refer to the [CustomizedDotLineChart example](https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomizedDotLineChart) in Recharts documentation.

You can see that the `CustomizedDot` component receives a `payload` prop, which contains the data item at that point. By adding a property such as `visible` (in your example, you can set the `visible` value depending on the viewport width, updating it on resize events), you can do:

```
const CustomizedDot = (props) => {
  const { cx, cy, stroke, payload, value } = props;

  if (payload.visible) {
    return (
      <svg x={cx - 4} y={cy - 4} width={8} height={8} fill="white">
        <g transform="translate(4 4)">
          <circle r="4" fill="black" />
          <circle r="2" fill="white" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    );
  }

  return null;
};
```

Answer (score -4):

Based on the Recharts API, I believe the parameter you are looking for is the `payload` parameter, which is part of the `Tooltip` component.
Pass an object that contains only the data points that you want to be clickable.

Link for reference: http://recharts.org/#/en-US/api/Tooltip